# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Trigger on Google Images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

We need a way to automatically create a Pub/Sub trigger on new compute images (preferably triggered on a specific image family). Alternatively, we know that Pub/Sub on GCS buckets, but we have not found a way to automate transferring images to a GCS bucket.

For some background: we are automating image baking through packer and we need this piece to trigger a terraform creation. We know that a cron job can be created to simply poll images when they are created, but we are wondering if there is already support for such a trigger in GCP.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a Stackdriver Logging export sink that publishes to Pub/Sub and is triggered by a specific filter ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2)). For example:

```js
resource.type="gce_image"
jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.images.insert"
jsonPayload.event_type="GCE_OPERATION_DONE"
```

[image]

To trigger it only for a specific family you can use this other filter below but `protoPayload.request.family` is only present when the API request is received and not when it is actually fulfilled (maybe you could add some delay in your processing function if needed)

```js
resource.type="gce_image"
protoPayload.request."@type"="type.googleapis.com/compute.images.insert"
protoPayload.request.family="FAMILY-NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to create a cloud function with --trigger-topic={your pub sub topic} and then filter only the images that you want to act on based on some environment variables on the cloud function

Psuedo code
1. create a pub sub topic for images being inserted in the GCR

```
    gcloud pubsub topics create projects/<project_id>/topics/gcr
```

2. This will now publish all messages corresponding to all images being inserted/modified/deleted in the repo
3. Create a cloud function that has the function signature thus

```
// contents of index.js
// use the Storage function from google-coud node js api to work on storages
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage

const Storage = require(@google-cloud/storage).Storage;

function moveToStorageBucket(pubSubEvents, context, callback) {
 /* this is how the pubsub comes from GCR
{"data":{"@type":"... .v1.PuSubMessage", "attribute":null, "data": "<base 64 encoded>"},
 "context":{..other details}}
data that is base 64 encoded in in this format
{ "action":"INSERT","digest":"<image name>","tag":<"tag name>"}
*/
    const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubSubEvents.data, 'base64').toString())
    // get image name from the environment variable passed
    const IMAGE_NAME = process.env.IMAGE_NAME;
    if (data.digest.indexOf(IMAGE_NAME) !== -1) {
     // your action here...
    }
}
module.exports.moveToStorageBucket = moveToStorageBucket;
```

4. deploy the cloud function

```
gcloud functions deploy <function_name> --region <region> --runtime=nodejs8 --trigger-topic=<topic created> --entry-point=moveToStorageBucket --set-env-vars=^--^IMAGE_NAME=<your image name>
```

Hope that helps